# Generic infix function with several upper bounds

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to do this

```
infix fun Int.divBy (_denom: Int): Rational {
    var num = this.toBigInteger()
    var denom = _denom.toBigInteger()

    // reduce result
    val result = Rational(num, denom)
    result.reduce()

    // return
    println("Returning: Rational $result")
    return result
}
```

but for Long, Int and BigInteger, and without having to rewrite the same for all of them. I tried this, but I get an error:

```
infix fun <T> T.divBy (_denom: T): Rational where
    T: Int, T:BigInteger, T: Long
    {
     ....
}
```

So that things like `val third = 1 divBy 3` can be done.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g01Yh.png)

Comment: The `where` clause works like an "and", not an "or", so the error is telling you that something cannot be an `Int`, a `Long` AND a `BigInteger` at the same time (empty intersection). You would have to use a common parent type instead, but there is none in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is not possible, because there is no interface for "something convertable to BigInteger". Still, you can keep most of your code in a single function receiving `BigInteger` objects and provide multiple functions for just converting to `BigInteger`:

```kotlin
infix fun Int.divBy(denom: Int): Rational = toBigInteger() divBy denom.toBigInteger()
infix fun Long.divBy(denom: Long): Rational = toBigInteger() divBy denom.toBigInteger()

inline infix fun BigInteger.divBy (denom: BigInteger): Rational {
    // reduce result
    val result = Rational(this, denom)
    result.reduce()

    // return
    println("Returning: Rational $result")
    return result
}
```

Edit (@ademord): the final solution looks like this, after cleaning it up:

```kotlin
infix fun Int.divBy(denom: Int): Rational = toBigInteger() divBy denom.toBigInteger()
infix fun Long.divBy(denom: Long): Rational = toBigInteger() divBy denom.toBigInteger()
infix fun BigInteger.divBy (denom: BigInteger): Rational = Rational(this, denom).reduce()
```

As a side note, it can't be done with generics and upper bounds, because their main purpose is that the code inside the function knows what is the type of `T`. `where` clause is used to specify multiple requirements that `T` needs to satisfy altogether. Upper bounds are ANDed, not ORed. Note that if they would be ORed then we would still have to add runtime type checks and casts, which is exactly what we try to avoid providing upper bounds (thanks @Tenfour04 for pointing this out).

Comment: Worth mentioning, the OP's code didn't work because when you put multiple upper bounds, it has to satisfy all of them, not one of them. Which logically makes sense because the point of generics is for the type and available members to be known.

Comment: omg you are a genius. thank you so much. I further simplified the last divBy with infix fun BigInteger.divBy (denom: BigInteger): Rational = Rational(this, denom).reduce()

Comment: @Ademord I approved your edit, but I still feel like it is worth inlining the inner function, even if Kotlin complains about it. Maybe I'm wrong and this is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, updated @Tenfour04